# Laravel only allow owner user to access route

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

I have an application that has users and products. Only the product owners should be able to view the product.

If a user guesses a product id they might be able to view the product. For example

```
http://booker.app/admin/products/32
```

Following that link would allow any logged in user to view the product with id 32.

This is the route in question:

```
Route::middleware(['middleware' => 'auth'])->prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
});
```

My products controller show method:

```
public function show(Product $product)
{        
    if($product->user_id !== Auth::user()->id){        
        return $this->forbidden('admin/products');
    }

    return $this->makeResponse('admin.products.product', compact('product'));
}
```

The forbidden and makeResponse functions simply check if the request was an ajax request and if so returns json.

As you can see I'm using route model binding and I'm checking if the authorised user is the same as product  user_id. Basically is there a better way of checking if the user is the owner of the product.

Comment: Using [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#writing-policies) is the most "laravel" way of doing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Laravel you can define [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#writing-policies) in order to specify ACL and access logic to your data layer.

For example create the class `ProductPolicy`:

```
class ProductPolicy
{

    public function show(User $user, Product $product)
    {
         return $user->id === $product->user_id;
    }

}
```

Then bind the policy to the `Product` model inserting the following line into `$policies` array in `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
protected $policies = [
    Product::class => ProductPolicy::class,
];
```

Now in your controller method you can use the following syntax to authorize the user to do a certain action

```
public function show(Product $product)
{
    $this->authorizeForUser(Auth::user(), 'show', [$product]);

    return $this->makeResponse('admin.products.product', compact('product'));
}
```

The method `authorizeForUser` will call the `show` method of your Policy, which will return `true` only if the product belongs to the authenticated user.

Hope it helps.